# How to see a local running webserver from a remote location

Tags: python, webserver, remote-access, remote, flask

I would appreciate some pointers or help for my particular situation: (apologies if I mistake any terminology)

**The situation**

I have a desktop computer on location A running linux where I am doing development (from docker containers but I don't know if that is relevant to this question) and the results of this is a webserver running on `0.0.0.0:portX` using something similar to flask.

I can connect to this computer from another computer running windows in location B through a VPN. The tools I have in my windows computer are SuperPutty and Visual Studio Code. With superPutty I can run a terminal on computer A from computer B where I can access all the necessary commands (docker, running the python scripts etc).  With Visual Studio Code I can do development on A from B without problem.

In the past I have tried to do Remote Desktop from B to A but have failed.

**My question**

Running the python-flask scripts in computer A produces a web server that I can visualize with a browser in computer A (when I am physically present in location A)

I want to see these results from computer B (while in location B). How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Does this help? https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/remote-control-linux-windows/

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried Remote Desktop and failed. Is there any other option?

Comment: I don't get this. If you are running a VPN, why can't you just point the browser at the remote VPN endpoint to get the site?

Comment: so if I point the browser to that IP, I get what in the machine would be `0.0.0.0`?